# UIStackView has no member delegate error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm learning how to program in Swift. 
At one step in the iOS Developer Library

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1

it tells me to add the command:

```
nameTextField.delegate = self
```

After entering the Command a Error pops up saying:

> Value of type 'UIStackView' has no Member 'delegate'

Please someone have a solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Matej! You might want to review this link when asking your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also you should format your code using the '{}' button.

Comment: Can u display your code snippet here?

Comment: you need to show your code, in particular the declaration of `nameTextField` - it appears to be a `UIStackView`, not a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.